# Convert SQL code to LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

Can anyone convert this to LINQ?

```
select distinct  t.Product_ID   from Product  as t
join Product_UserQuestionaire  as s
on  t.Product_ID = s.Product_ID where t.Product_ID not in  (


select distinct  t.Product_ID  from Product  as t
join Product_UserQuestionaire  as s
on  t.Product_ID = s.Product_ID 
where  s.SpaceID =7 )
```

Comment: SO is here to help people, not do stuff for them. You'll find some good examples of distinct queries at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#distinct1. Try it for yourself, then come back with proper question if you hit problems :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hey thanks for that constructive criticism. I tried and i got it. Thanks

Comment: How about sharing your solution so that others can benefit from your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

When having problems with LINQ try breaking down the subqueries into IQueryable statements. These don't execute unless you hit .ToList or enumerate the results, so it's a good way to separate out the logic of the query.

However in this case the SQL query is over-complicated:

```
            var query = (from t in Product
                    join s in Product_UserQuestionaire on t.Product_ID equals s.Product_ID
                    where s.SpaceID != 7
                    select t.Product_ID).Distinct();
```